# JQuery Change Background Color of Dropdown List Element Based on Title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this code, it originated with just a blank table with a select tag:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="e2">
                <option value="green">Green</option>
                <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                <option value="red">Red</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is generated with jQuery functions that format the selection as a list of nested spans:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr> 
        <td>
            <b class="tablesaw-cell-label">Status</b>
            <span class="tablesaw-cell-content">
                <select tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" id="e2" aria-hidden="true">
                    <option value="green">Green</option>
                    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                    <option value="red">Red</option>
                </select>
                <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below" style="width: 64px;" dir="ltr">
                    <span class="selection">
                        <span tabindex="0" class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="select2-e2-container">
                            <span title="Green" class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-e2-container">Green</span>
                            <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to change the color by using jQuery of the individual background colors based on the title of the element after the page is loaded. Here is my current color change function. This runs after the dropdown list is created and formatted by the `select2` function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#e1').select2();
    $('#e2').select2();

    $('.select2-selection.select2-selection--single span.select2-selection__rendered').each(function () {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        console.log(title);
        if (title === 'Green') {
            $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'green');
        }
        if (title === 'Yellow') {
            $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'yellow');
        }
        if (title === 'Red') {
            $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });
});
```

I have been able to simplify the code and change the color of all elements as a single color. However, I'm trying to change the color of each selection element based on the title of that element and not change the other elements's background color.

Comment: Put it in a codepen/fiddle please: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: U are trying to change the color of span acodding with the selected option ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Yes, I'm trying to change each individual span according to the selection. As of right now, the color changes all three selections to green.

Comment: @ann0nC0d3r I can toss this entire page into jsfiddle, it's just a lot of code.

Comment: here's the full code: the lines which we are concentrating are at the bottom of this fiddle in js lines 16364 and up. https://jsfiddle.net/8hknqjax/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your other post that got deleted, I think this is what you're after:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#e1').select2();
    $('#e2').select2().on('change', function(){
        $(this).next().find('.select2-selection').css({
            backgroundColor: this.value
        });
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Just listen for the change event and update the CSS then.

Here's an updated fiddle from your other post: https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/ea7q41k7/

Comment: That's perfect, it takes care of it perfectly. Advertently, had I not lost 6 rep I'd +1 you. Thank you for an answer that made what I was after work. Thanks

Comment: lol You're welcome.  The SO community can be fickle at times.  Honestly, I prefer more info to less and I don't see anything wrong with the fiddle you posted.  Oh well.  Glad I could find a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Given the HTML structure which you state that Select2 is generating, your selector is incorrect. The `select2-selection` and `select2-selection--single` are both applied to the same element, so the space between them needs to be replaced with a class selector; `.`.

Also note that you don't need the `if` statement as the `title` matches the colour you're setting with `.css()`. Try this:

```
$('.select2-selection.select2-selection--single span.select2-selection__rendered').each(function () {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', title);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/n52vay34/1/)

Comment: This is really close, I think, it's just not changing the color to match it's selection, it's only changing the entire selection to green instead of just the "Green" selection.

Answer (score 2):

You missing the `.` in the selector so,

use this,

```
$('.select2-selection.select2-selection--single span.select2-selection__rendered')
```

instead of this

$`('.select2-selection select2-selection--single span.select2-selection__rendered')`

Comment: yeah sorry, I had already fixed that in the webpage and forgot to edit in SO, it's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

this is an example put it in each function or modify it to whatever you wanna do.

```
$('#e2').on('click', function(){
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).css('background-color', title);
});
```

I have built it on val() but I am sure you can change it. 
[JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/n52vay34/6/)