# Add color to option in bootstrap multiselect on condition

Tags: css, bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to create bootstrap multiselect drop-down 
in the select list for some of the items on some condition from back-end 
I need to change the background color like

[image]

is there any way  I can provide color attribute to options while creating the multiselect?Can I use dataprovider and add color attribute there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the background colour of Dropdown list depending on values using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567808/change-the-background-colour-of-dropdown-list-depending-on-values-using-jquery)

Comment: @MattHamer5 yes I will have to adapt it a little as per bootstrap components but I think it will do the trick...thanks a lot.